# TV series where a boy moves to a weird town with an episode where an angel statue cries

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

In my country, when I was a child, I used to watch this TV series, dubbed to my native language.

It was about a weird town, where always something happened. Each of the people who lived there knew about it. The main character (a boy) recently moved to the town, and quickly makes friends with one of the neighborhood kids.

This kid tells him the town is weird, and ends his explanation with: "People breathe with their mouths here." (Everything is backwards?)

I'm not sure know, but episodes later, one of main character's friends (perhaps the one I mentioned above?) dies. The main character and other friends go to the cemetery to visit his grave, which has a very big statue of an angel.

A single tear rolls down the statue's cheek after they leave, and the episode ends. It seemed to be from the late 80's or the early 90's. I'm pretty sure it was an American production.

UPDATE: If I recalled correctly, the dead kid had a sister.

Comment: Could it be Round the Twist or Are You Afraid of the Dark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Eerie, Indiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eerie,_Indiana) that ran for a single season in the early 90s.

> The series revolves around Marshall Teller, a teenager whose family moves to the desolate town of Eerie, Indiana, population of 16,661. While moving into his new home, he meets Simon Holmes, one of the few normal people in Eerie. Together, they are faced with bizarre scenarios, which include discovering a sinister group of intelligent dogs that are planning on taking over the world, and meeting a tornado hunter who is reminiscent of Captain Ahab. They also confront numerous urban legends such as Bigfoot and a still-living Elvis Presley. Although the show was host to a plethora of jokes, it also featured a serious tone.

One of his classmates dies in episode 7 and in the end of the episode, the angel statue displayed above his headstone sheds a tear. You can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zULD_rp0CTg). Here's the intro: